# Get view index sizes programmatically

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm familiar with the "Manage Views" tool in Domino Administrator, and wondered if anyone had come up with a way to access the view Index size programmatically.  Ideally I'd use LotusScript but any other method would be great too.

I'm hoping to analyze which views are actually used across a large number of databases, without having to extract the info manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible in LotusScript. But the index size could be retrieved with the C-API function `NIFGetCollectionData`.
You need to open the database with `NSFDbOpen`, get the view with `NIFFindView`, open the view with `NIFOpenCollection` and finally get the size with `NIFGetCollectionData`. And of course you need to call `NIFCloseCollection` and `NSFDbClose` to clean up.

Comment: This was the sort of answer I was expecting, and I was semi-resigned to fiddling with API calls.  However, my data doesn't need to be real time, so I'm going to write some script to pull out the data from the log docs as  per D Bugger's answer.
Thanks for the answer, Dietmar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an easier way, but you'll probably have to develop the necessary tooling yourself. A small quest in 6 steps:

1. open the log.nsf database for your server
2. open the view Usage/by Size
3. open a usage document for a fairly large database, e.g. mail/yourmail.nsf
4. the document shows all views and their (index) sizes
5. open the Document Properties box (Alt-Enter)
6. the field AllViewInfo (RichText) contains that data

Downsides:

- AFAIK there is no ready-made LotusScript library for log.nsf.
- those sizes are collected during the night, so they're not up to date
- going through a rich-text's data can be daunting

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that. Just had a look at the structure of the docs, and that's got everything I need.  I've no fear or RT, just didn't know those docs existed till now - oops!

Comment: There are many hidden gems in Notes that really need to be uncovered.